# Does PHPStorm understand @constructs or @constructor for JavaScript?

Tags: phpstorm, jsdoc

I'm a little confused as to which JSDoc describes a constructor function for a class, and if PHPStorm understands either.

When I research which JSDoc to use I keep coming across two versions. There is `@constructs` and `@constructor`.

- Do these two tags mean the same thing?
- Which tag should I use in my JSDoc?
- Is there a benefit in PHPStorm for code complete or intellisense using either?

Here are some references.

https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagConstructor

https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagConstructs

Now I understand that `@constructs` should be used with `@lends` but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to mark a function as a constructor, @constructor is the right choice. @constructs only applies to a lent function and may be used with @lends tag only (that can only appear on object literals). See [this Wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagLends) for more info on @lends tag.
Note that PHPStorm supports both tags for type hinting/navigation